# Passing 2-D array with dynamic size between functions in C/++

Tags: c++, c, arrays, dynamic-arrays, character-arrays

This is "popular" question so I already checked the similar threads but still didnt resolve my issue.

**How can I declare 2-D array to hold "strings" - I need array of array of chars AFAIK - and use it as argument to 5 functions one after another where I can pass it by reference and update the content dynamically so following function can compare it. (I might get 10 "strings" or even *empty* array, so I want to do it correctly with dynamic array coz array content is different from system to system).**

"string" => C style string aka array of chars. MAXLEN < 32;

C solution would be more disirable but if vectors can work, why not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution in C is as follows:

```
char **p_strings = calloc(num_strings, sizeof(*p_strings));

for (i = 0; i < num_strings; i++)
{
    // Allocate storage for the i-th string (always leave room for '\0')
    p_strings[i] = calloc(len_string[i]+1, sizeof(*p_strings[i]));
}


...

// Call a function
my_function(p_strings, num_strings);
```

You will need to remember to `free` all this data when you're done with it.

If you need to alter the length of a string, or change the number of strings, you will have to do some fairly painful reallocation.  So if you're working in C++, you should probably just be using a `std::vector<std::string>`.

```
std::vector<std::string> strings;

strings.push_back("Foo");
strings.push_back("Bar");

...

my_function(strings);
```

You can even get const pointers to C-style strings for each element, using `c_str()`.

Comment: I have to add new "strings" only or may I say ROWs... I dont edit them or change their len.

Comment: Okay that last line bout .c_str() might do what I need. Can you show when to free it ? I need em in different functions remember. Thx for answer looks promising.

Comment: @cat9: You don't need to free anything for the C++ solution.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming C++; for this I see no problem with using a vector to string (the string serves as the second dimension):

```
void foo(vector<string> v) {
    cout << v[0]; // Assuming the elements exist!
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    vector<string> vString; // Make the vector

    vString.push_back("something"); // Add a string

    foo(vString); // Print out 'something'
}
```

In your edit you also described that the only thing that will change would be the actual string, so instead of `push_back`ing your strings when they are needed, you can init the vector with the length:

```
vector<string> vString(10); // Assuming a size of 10
```

and then use them normally:

```
vString[4] = "something";
```

and (in response to the comment), to resize at runtime:

```
vString.resize(15); // Make it bigger, generates new blank strings
```

Comment: If I read the OP's question correctly, he just needs a singly-nested vector.

Comment: so if I do this in foo(), memcpy(v[1][32],new, strlen(new)); will it work on vector?

Comment: I just need array of array of chars which is by design 2-D array like in Oli's answer?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth - You're right, I misread the 2D to mean a double-nest. Edited.

Comment: Well number of strings isnt known either ... so thus is dynamic len and I cant use predefined size, well I can ofc even less then 10 but lets not do it.

Comment: @cat9 if you want to change the size at runtime, just use `vector::resize`; i.e `vString.resize(15);`, it now contains more elements. You can do the same to make it smaller.

Comment: @Schnommus  but isnt just pushbacking better? ofc I have to use iterrators then to parse all elements?

Comment: @cat9 Well that depends completely on what your algorithm is. Up to you to decide ;)

Comment: Asking you for possibilitys mate :) Im not much of a C++ guru

Comment: @cat9 If you're resizing in chunks, I reckon `resize`'d be faster; but that's entirely subjective, it might be faster to hand-code your own `push_back` loop.